# Extended Desktop: Mouse pointer jumps down about 120 pixels when moving from main to 2nd screen

Tags: windows-10

Problem as described in question title. Do you have any ideas what could be the reason for this behavior?

I have 2 screens (1920x1200). The 2nd one is on the left of the main screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In windows 7 and windows 10 (and presumably also in other versions) you can tell windows how monitors are positioned relative to each other.

In the OP's screenshot you can see how monitor 1 is to the right and slightly below monitor 2. This means that in two ereas you can not move your mouse from one screen to the other screen and that windows will try to adjust the position of the cursor when you move between screens.

Windows 10 screenshot as added by the OP:

[image: Screenshot from windows 10]

And the windows 7 screenshot from a now deleted comment.
[image]

Comment: Perfect answer.  Thanks.